# Fatal error: Class 'Sql' not found

Tags: php, mysqli, localhost, php-include

I am trying to define the Host and the Root path in my localhost. the website was working on my server. I wanted to back it up in my localhost. But I am not sure how to define the localhost Host and Root path.

Following is how I had it defined on my website server.

```
<?php
    define('HOST','http://website.in/',false); // false mean that HOST cannot be used as hOsT
    define('ROOT', '/home/website/public_html/', false);
    define('CDN', HOST.'photo/', false);
    define('PROXY',' ',false);
    $db_data = array() ;
    $db_data['host'] = 'localhost' ;
    $db_data['user'] = 'root' ;
    $db_data['pass'] = '' ; 
    $db_data['db'] = 'localdatabase' ;

?>
```

when I moved to localserver, I changed it to the following.

But I am getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'Sql' not found`.

I am pretty sure it is because of some path misconfiguration.

Here is how my directory hierarchy in localhost.

```
www/Website/includes/app.php
www/Website/includes/setting.php

www/Website/modules/Sql.php
```

Here is the code for app.php

```
<?php

    include_once( 'includes/setting.php' ) ;
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');


    function loadModule($className){
        if(file_exists(ROOT.'modules/'.$className.'.php'))
            require_once(ROOT.'modules/'.$className.'.php');
    }

    spl_autoload_register('loadModule');


    $DB = new mysqli( $db_data['host'] , $db_data['user'] , $db_data['pass'] , $db_data['db']);    
    Sql::init($DB);

    @session_start();
    if(!isSet($_SESSION['mmu']))
        $_SESSION['mmu']=0;



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
define('ROOT', '/home/website/public_html/', false);
```

into

```
define('ROOT', 'www/Website', false);
```

or some other path where you have files on your localhost (for example `c:\xampp\www` or `'/home/website/`)